# Stop changing my DNS!

Tags: linux-mint, dns

I am using Linux Mint and tethering Internet through my phone.

Every time I enable tethering, my DNS on computer is being set to 127.0.0.1 which results in being unable to resolve any name. I have to manually open "network settings" panel and change DNS to 8.8.8.8 (google's DNS). It works till next time I enable tethering (that is, multiple times per day).

I have tried saving them in network connection panel for this particular connection, but it seems to be completely ignored.

I have also tried to edit /etc/resolv.conf and even remove write permissions, but sooner or later it gets overwritten anyway.

What is changing my DNS settings and how to make it stop?

Comment: Sounds like you have a fight going on between `network-manager`, `resolvconf`, and `dnsmasq`.  The lazy way of "fixing" it so that /etc/resolv.conf remains unchanged would be to edit it one last time, and then set the immutable flag via chattr - `sudo chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @ivanivan chattr: Operation not supported while reading flags on /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: install `dnsmasq` if it isn't already installed.  optionally configure it to use google's 8.8.8.8 as its forwarder (upstream/parent resolver).  `apt-get purge resolvconf`.  configure NetworkManager as in the dupe link above (alternatively, get rid of network manager too and configure your network interfaces manually by editing `/etc/network/interfaces`).   With a DNS resolver like `dnsmasq` installed, you should **always** use 127.0.0.1 as your dns server - it's a local cache speeding up all DNS resolution.  Other machines on your LAN/WLAN/etc should also use your Mint box as their resolver.